# Deleting a modified object from a set in a no-op?

Tags: ruby, set

See the example below

```
require "set"
s = [[1, 2], [3, 4]].to_set # s = {[1, 2], [3, 4]}
m = s.max_by {|a| a[0]} # m = [3, 4]
m[0] = 9 # m = [9, 4], s = {[1, 2], [9, 4]}
s.delete(m) # s = {[1, 2], [9, 4]} ?????
```

This behaves differently from an array. (If we remove `.to_set`, we will get `s = [[1, 2]]` which is expected.) Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug or at least I'd call it a bug. Some would call this "an implementation detail accidentally leaking to the outside world" but that's just fancy pants city-boy talk for *bug*.

The problem has two main causes:

1. You're modifying elements of the Set without Set knowing about it.
2. The standard Ruby [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is implemented as a Hash.

The result is that you're modifying the internal Hash's keys without the Hash knowing about it and that confuses the poor Hash into not really knowing what keys it has anymore. The Hash class has a [`rehash` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-rehash):

> **rehash → hsh**
>
> Rebuilds the hash based on the current hash values for each key. If values of key objects have changed since they were inserted, this method will reindex *hsh*.
>
> ```
> a = [ "a", "b" ]
> c = [ "c", "d" ]
> h = { a => 100, c => 300 }
> h[a]       #=> 100
> a[0] = "z"
> h[a]       #=> nil
> h.rehash   #=> {["z", "b"]=>100, ["c", "d"]=>300}
> h[a]       #=> 100
> ```

Notice the interesting behavior in the example included with the `rehash` documentation. Hashes keep track of things using the `k.hash` values for the key `k`. If you have an array as a key and you change the array, you can change the array's `hash` value as well; the result is that the Hash still has that array as a key but the Hash won't be able to find that array as a key because it will be looking in the bucket for the new `hash` value but the array will be in the bucket for the old `hash` value. But, if you `rehash` the Hash, it will all of a sudden be able to find all of its keys again and the senility goes away. Similar problems will occur with non-array keys: you just have to change the key in such a way that its `hash` value changes and the Hash containing that key will get confused and wander around lost until you `rehash` it.

The [Set class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) uses a Hash internally to store its members and the members are used as the hash's keys. So, if you change a member, the Set will get confused. If Set had a `rehash` method then you could kludge around the problem by slapping the Set upside the head with `rehash` to knock some sense into it; alas, there is no such method in Set. However, you can monkey patch your own in:

```
class Set
  def rehash
    @hash.rehash
  end
end
```

Then you can change the keys, call `rehash` on the Set, and your `delete` (and various other methods such as `member?`) will work properly.

Comment: Do you believe hashes were implement that way because the overhead for Ruby to keep track of changes to keys and performing `rehash` internally would be too great?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think just tracking the changes to the keys would be expensive, you'd end up needing change-callbacks on everything, no? So yeah, probably a lot of expense for an uncommon case.