# Is this expected behaviour for a Set of arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, set, concatenation

We're doing a bit of work in Ruby 1.8.7 that requires traversing and partitioning an undirected graph, that has been failing weirdly in production. When I distil the failing code down to its barest components, I get this strangely failing test:

```
it 'should be able to clear a ruby set of arrays' do
  a = ["2", "b", "d"]
  b = ["1", "a", "c", "e", "f"]
  set = Set.new([a, b])
  a.concat(b)

  p "before clear: #{set.inspect}"
  set.clear
  p "after clear: #{set.inspect}"
  set.size.should == 0
end
```

The test fails with this output:

```
"before clear: #<Set: {[\"1\", \"a\", \"c\", \"e\", \"f\"], [\"2\", \"b\", \"d\", \"1\", \"a\", \"c\", \"e\", \"f\"]}>"
"after clear: #<Set: {[\"2\", \"b\", \"d\", \"1\", \"a\", \"c\", \"e\", \"f\"]}>"

expected: 0
     got: 1 (using ==)
```

Attempts to delete from the set also behave in strange ways. I'm guessing that Ruby is getting hung up on the hash values of the keys in the array changing under concat(), but surely I should still be able to clear the Set. Right?

Comment: There's no problem in ruby 1.9.3p125 like yours.

Comment: I just found this, which answers the question about deletes. But not why clear fails.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361400/deleting-a-modified-object-from-a-set-in-a-no-op

Comment: set.clear uses hash.clear to clear it's internal hash. Hash.clear uses hash.for_each to delete each hash item. So if there is a bug that effects delete, it will effect clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this, if you duplicate the set after you modify the keys, the new set will have the updated keys and clear properly. So setting `set = set.dup` will fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The .dup approach was indeed my first work-around, and did as advertised.

I ended up adding the following monkey-patch to Set:

```
class Set
  def rehash
    @hash.rehash
  end
end
```

which allows me to rehash the set's keys after any operation that changes their hash values.

This appears to all be fixed in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work in JRuby. For JRuby, you're stuck with dup-ing the Set before performing any operations that require up-to-date keys.