# Behavior of altered array keys in hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

Ruby allows for a mutable object to be used as a hash key, and I was curious how this worked when the object is updated. It seems like the referenced object is irretrievable from key requests if it's updated.

```
key = [1,2]
test = {key => 12}

test               # => {[1, 2] => 12}
test[key]          # => 12
test[[1,2]]        # => 12
test[[1,2,3]]      # => nil

key << 3

test               # => {[1, 2, 3] => 12}
test[key]          # => nil
test[[1,2]]        # => nil
test[[1,2,3]]      # => nil
```

Why does this work this way? Why can't I provide a key to the hash which will return the value associated with the list I original used as a key?

Comment: The same underlying issue in a different disguise: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10361400/479863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#label-Hash+Keys):

> Two objects refer to the same hash key when their hash value is identical and the two objects are eql? to each other.

Mutating a key doesn't change the hash it's stored under.  After you mutate the key, trying to index with `[1,2]` matches the `hash` but not `eql?`, while `[1,2,3]` matches the `eql?` but isn't found by `hash`.

See [this article](http://jafrog.com/2012/10/07/mutable-objects-as-hash-keys-in-ruby.html) for a more elaborate explanation.

You can rehash `test`, however, to recalculate the hashes based on current key values:

```
test.rehash
test[[1,2,3]] # => 12
```

Comment: So basically Ruby lets you shoot yourself in the foot with built-in components. Didn't know about the rehash capability!

Answer (score 2):

```
class D
end

p D.new.methods.include?(:hash) #=> true
# so the D instance has a hash method. What does it do?
p D.new.hash #=> -332308361 # just some number
```

(Almost) every object in Ruby has a `hash` method. The Hash calls this method when the object is used as a key, and uses the resulting number to store and retrieve the key. (There are smart procedures to handle duplicate numbers (hash collisions)). Retrieving goes like this:

```
a_hash[[1,2,3]]
# the a_hash calls the hash method to the [1,2,3] object
# and checks if it has stored a value for the resulting number.
```

This number is only created once: when the key is added to the hash instance.
Problems arise when you start messing with the key after including it in a hash: the `hash`method of the object will differ from the one stored in the hash.

- Don't do that, or
- consider not using mutable objects as keys, or
- remember to do a timely:

  a_hash.rehash

which will recalculate all hash numbers.

Note: For strings keys, a copy is used for calculating the hash number, so modifying the original key won't matter.

Comment: To compliment this answer, it is crucial that the `hash` method depends on the content of the object, not the identity. So, different objects with the same content will have the same result of `hash`. `hash` and `object_id` are different.

Comment: I didn't get the line *For strings keys, a copy is used for calculating the hash number, so modifying the original key won't matter.* Could you elaborate more on his with an example? `a = "abc"
h = {a=>12}
p h[a] #=> 12
a << "d"
p a #=> "abcd"
p h[a] #=> nil`

Comment: @RubyLovely [string keys behave different than array keys.](http://ideone.com/8V6fVV)

Comment: @steenslag make sense now, but `Hash#rehash` need in both case. `+1` for the note,as I was not aware of.But yes key as a `string`,adheres your **Note**. Any idea why such implementation?

Answer (score 1):

It would be inconvenient if the identity of an array matters as the hash key. If you have a hash with a key `[1, 2]`, you want to be able to access that with a different array object `[1, 2]` that has the same content. You want access by the content, not the identity. That would mean that what particular object (with the particular object id) is stored as a key does not matter for a hash. All that matters is the content of the key at the time it was assigned to the hash.

Therefore, after doing `key << 3`, it makes sense that `test[key]` or `test[[1, 2, 3]]` does not return the stored value anymore because `key` at the time of assignment to `test` was `[1, 2]`.

The tricky thing is that `test[[1, 2]]` also returns `nil`. That is the limitation of Ruby.

If you want the hash to reflect the change made in the key objects, there is a method `Hash#rehash`.

```
test.rehash
test[key]          # => 12
test[[1,2]]        # => nil
test[[1,2,3]]      # => 12
```