# Unique objects in the ruby ​array

Tags: ruby

The program should produce only unique aircraft, it repeats the element array. uniq method doesn't help.

```
class Airplane

    attr_accessor :model        

    def initialize(model) 
        @model = model
    end
end

models  =   [ "Boeing 777-300ER",
              "Boeing 737-800",
              "Airbus А330-200", 
              "Airbus А330-300",
              "Airbus А321",
              "Airbus A320",
              "Sukhoi SuperJet 100"]
planes = []

150.times do

    model = models[rand(0..6)]
    plane = Airplane.new(model)

    planes << plane
```

try here # planes = planes.uniq doesn't help

```
    break if models.length == planes.length
end

# result
planes.uniq.each do |plane|   # <<<< uniq doesn't help
    puts "Model: #{plane.model}"
end
```

Comment: The strings in your list *are* all different — if you want to consider ones that share the part of the model before the hyphen to be the same, you need to make that explicit in code.

Comment: @Linuxios: That is irrelevant. `uniq` is called on the 150-element array of `Airplane`, not on the 7-element array of `String`. The issue is the lack of equality predicate on `Airplane` class.

Comment: %w [....]  or "Boeing_777_300ER" underscore?

Comment: @Amadan: I wouldn't call it *irrelevant*; at some point a model string comparison will be needed, though you are of course right about `Airplane#eql?` being the first problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise, no two objects are the same:

```
Object.new.eql?(Object.new)
# => false
```

Thus, where `#uniq` is concerned, all 150 `Airplane` instances are unique, with no duplicates.

The easiest way to fix this is to provide the uniqueness criterion to `#uniq`:

```
planes.uniq(&:model)
```

The other way is to define what "duplicate" means for the `Airplane` class:

```
class Airplane
  attr_accessor :model        

  def initialize(model) 
    @model = model
  end

  def ==(other)
    other.class == self.class && other.model == self.model
  end

  alias_method :eql?, :==

  def hash
    self.model.hash
  end
end
```

However, this solution will make two airplanes of the same model *the same airplane*, in all cases, which might have unintended consequences in other places.

Comment: why def hash method?

Comment: [Ruby: Why does `#hash` need to overridden whenever `#eql?` is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961311/ruby-why-does-hash-need-to-overridden-whenever-eql-is-overridden) (Same logic explained for `Hash` there holds for `#uniq`, whose docs explicitly mention `#eql?` and `#hash` are used.)

Comment: everything works thanks, I chose the second way, I don’t know where to put the first planes.uniq(&:model) and still displays elements 4 or 5, and in the models there are 7 of them, what could be the problem .size .length?

Comment: In the first way, just replace `planes.uniq` with `planes.uniq(&:model)` (e.g. `planes.uniq(&:model).each ...` in your third-from-last line). I don't know what you mean by "still displays elements 4 or 5".

Comment: I mean still display output

Comment: `planes = planes.uniq` would become `planes = planes.uniq(&:model)`, or `planes.uniq!(&:model)`. That line is a bit misplaced - it will work there, but it is inefficient, the right place for that line would be after the loop. But then you have `uniq` twice - just use one or the other, there's no need to repeat it. And I still don't understand "still displays elements 4 or 5"...?

Comment: 7 different planes models, and displays 3..6 unique planes output to be exact. 
 break if models.length == planes.length  
maybe this is the length?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I did not see that line, and did not test with it. I do not know what purpose it serves for you — you will break if you get 7 airplanes, which may be non-unique (if you moved the uniq line as I suggested earlier) and then `#uniq` will remove the dupes and give you less. I am not sure what result you are _trying_ to get — I was only dealing with the `#uniq` problem.

Comment: I definitely deleted break and 7 displays planes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing objects of a class, and each object is different even though they are of same instance type. You can override this behaviour by defining a comparison method for your class

```
class Aeroplane
    def ==(o)
      o.class == self.class && o.model == model
    end
end
```

Comment: This does not work; `#uniq` looks at `#eql?` (and `#hash`), not at `#==`.