# Return object after performing intersection of two arrays based on attribute

Tags: arrays, ruby, intersection

I have two arrays, both filled with objects that have numerous attributes. Both arrays are holding the same object types. I want to find where objects match based on their attribute `id`

Object example:

```
#<Link:0x00007fac5eb6afc8 @id = 2002001, @length=40, @area='mars' ...>
```

Example arrays filled with objects:

```
array_links = [<Link:0x00007fac5eb6afc8>, <Link:0x00007fdf5eb7afc2>, <Link:0x000081dag6zb7agg8>... ]
selected_links = [<Link:0x00007fad8ob6gbh5>, <Link:0x00007fdg7hh4tif4>, <Link:0x000081dag7ij5bhh9>... ]
```

If these were strings of the object IDs and there was a match, I could use:

```
intersection = array_links & selected_links
```

However I want to do this based on their attribute and return a matching object itself.
Something like:

```
intersection = array_links.select(&:id) & selected_links.select(&:id)
```

But of course, not that, as that doesn't work, any ideas? :)

Comment: Are they meant to be the same? Or is it just based on their id attribute?

Comment: Based on their ID. Essentially there will be some objects that are the same in both arrays, however they have been given different Object IDs, so I need to use their attribute to find the match, and return the object itself (from either array)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921999/how-to-find-and-return-a-duplicate-value-in-array

Comment: `array_links.select(&:id) & selected_links.select(&:id)` should return you an array of the id's which are common in both arrays. Of course it means that your `Link` objects understand the method _id_. Why do you think it would not work?

Comment: `select(&:id)` in this case sounds strange because all it does is to gather those elements whose `id` return value is truthy, it kind of doesn't relate to the problem stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can:

## 1 :

override the `eql?(other)` method then the array intersection will work

```rb
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  def eql?(other)
    self.class == other.class && self.id == other&.id # classes comparing class is a guard here
  end
  
  # you should always update the hash if you are overriding the eql?() https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961965/5872935
  def hash
    self.id.hash
  end 
end
```

## 2:

use `array.select`:

```rb
array_links.flat_map {|i| selected_links.select {|k|  k.user_id == i.user_id }}
```

Comment: @EricDuminil good point, thanks, updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If they are the same object in memory, ie `array_links = [<Link:0x123]` and `selected_links = [<Link:0x123>]`, then your solution of:

```
intersection = array_links & selected_links
```

Should work.

If they are not, you could loop over you `array_links` and `select` those which are in `selected_links`:

```
intersection = array_links.select do |link|
  link.id.in? selected_links.map(&:id)
end
```

The result will be the same if you loop over `selected_links` and `select` those in  `array_links`.

Depending on your resources and the size of these arrays, you could memoize `selected_links.map(&:id)` to prevent this from being re-built on each iteration.