# nil result despite both #hash and #eql? evaluating to true, when looking up a key in a hash?

Tags: ruby

I am wondering why this ruby hash evaluates to nil when I shovel into an array (which is the key for the hash) when the key is the same, according to #eql? and checking for the hashes equality.

```
some_arr = [1]
=> [1]
my_hash = { some_arr => "value" }
=> {[1]=>"value"}
my_hash[some_arr]
=> "value"
some_arr << 2
=> [1, 2]
my_hash[some_arr]
=> nil
my_hash
=> {[1, 2]=>"value"}
```

Both #eql? and checking for the hashes equality evaluate to true:

```
some_arr.hash == my_hash.keys[0].hash
=> true
some_arr.eql? my_hash.keys[0]
=> true
```

Not even using the array [1,2] gives the value:

```
my_hash[[1,2]]
=> nil
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, your hash becomes outdated. Use `rehash` to solve your problem.

```rb
my_hash.rehash
```

Comment: For some explanation on why `rehash` is needed, see this related [question on sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10361400/479863).

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use an object as a key you shouldn't tamper with the key after the fact for this very reason, but if you do B-M has the solution here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why it is necessary to execute `rehash`, though the link given by @muistooshort does that for you.